# How can I tell if a serial connection is sending bytes okay?

Tags: microcontroller, motor

I have a Teensy connected to a Pololu motor controller. If I send bytes over USB (using Pololu Serial Transmitter v1.3) I can get it to work (For instance, 0x85 0x00 0x20 makes the motor run at slow speed). However when I attempt the same thing in my sketch I cannot get it to work. This leads me to the conclusion that there may be a problem with my serial wires or with the motor control board itself.

So I'd like to be able to test that the serial connection is working, can I accomplish this with a multimeter or something?

My code, just in case there's something wrong with that is:

```
#define rxPin 10
#define txPin 9
SoftwareSerial smcSerial = SoftwareSerial(rxPin, txPin);
```

loop:

```
smcSerial.write(0x85);
smcSerial.write((byte) 0x00);
smcSerial.write(0x20);
```

Answer (score 2):

If you are using the auto-baud rate setup for Pololu motor systems you first need to send "a baud rate indication byte", basically you send an 0xAA first, and after any power on or reset. See descriptions of serial settings here: https://www.pololu.com/docs/0J44/6.1

It does not seem to say if the "indication byte" is acceptable with every transmission.  Overall it may be best to just set the system up to a known baud rate ahead of time, or use the default (which seems to be 9600).

To physically verify transmission from your Teensy controller you could also put an LED and resistor on the transmit line (say with a 500 ohm resistor to gnd or V+).  The LED should flash briefly with each transmission packet, though at higher baud rates the flashes will be quite short, (so if that is a problem do some testing at lower rates for verification).

Answer (score 0):

I cannot comment yet, so I'm posting this as an answer:

Did you forget `smcSerial.begin(9600)` in your `setup()` function?  
Also, make sure you pass the proper baud rate to `begin()`, 9600 is just an example.  
And no, a multimeter would be of no use troubleshooting this problem.

Comment: yes I have begin in setup, how do I know what the proper baud rate is, doesn't it auto detect?

Comment: I checked Pololu website and it does say it autodetects baud rate. So I am guessing 9600 will be just fine. So it should work. Double check your connection (pin 10 -> Pololu TX and pin 9 to Pololu RX), try adding a delay (of lets say 1 second) in your loop if you don't already have one.

Answer (score 0):

My go-to tool for testing serial data and/or pulse modulation is to use a digital storage oscilloscope.

Traditionally DSO are quite pricey. But recently there have been a few hand-held designs coming out of the hobbyist/maker market that are good enough to troubleshoot most digital communications. Google "DSO nano" and "DIY DSO".

If even hobby grade DSO seem too much to spend on you can always use some software to transform your sound card into an oscilloscope. In fact, this is what I've done. Note that your sound card is crap at capturing exact voltage values because the input is capacitively coupled. But it's good at capturing digital serial data - enough that you can actually decode the data yourself.

I've only ever used [XOscope](http://xoscope.sourceforge.net/) on Linux but you can google "software oscilloscope mac" or "software oscilloscope windows" in you need similar software on other platforms.